# Array of object is not getting filtered and value inside filtered items also not getting changed in the following Vue.js method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to filter an array of objects and based on the condition and set disabled to true.

```
      allUsers: [
      {
        id: "id1",
        name: "David",
        prof: "programmer",
        tasksNumber: 4,
        isAtWork: true,
        disabled: false,
      },
      {
       id: "id2",
        name: "Jessy",
        prof: "programmer",
        tasksNumber: 6,
        isAtWork: true,
        disabled: false,
      },
...
...
      ]
```

Then inside a method, I am trying to filter allUsers based on condition but in console log I always see the all users so filtering and mapping both are not working:

```
editUsers(){
    if (some condition here) {
    this.aaUsers = this.allUsers.filter(user => user.prof === "designer" ||
          !tasksAllowedNumbers.includes(user.tasksNumber)).map(user=> user.disabled = true)
    }
...
}
```

I've seen many examples on stackoverflow but none of them solved the problem. So the goal is based on if condition filter unmatching professions and if tasksAllowedNumbers array doesn't include users tasksNumber then set the user disabled to true. How can be it achieved correctly?

Comment: `.map(user => user.disabled = true)` returns an array of booleans. Something like `.map(user => ({ ...user, disabled: true }) )` works?

Comment: Will it set true value only for filtered users who meet the condition requirements?

Comment: Yes. The it only `map`s the filtered users

Comment: @adiga the problem is that I need to get this.allusers full array of objects and only modify  disabled value for some unmatches The point is that I should not get new array from only filtered items.

Comment: Then you only need to remove `this.aaUsers = this.allUsers.filter(...)` assignment from your code. It already sets `disabled` property of objects inside the `allUsers` for the filtered users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function should return a object. Please find the code below.

```js
let allUsers = [
      {
        id: "id1",
        name: "David",
        prof: "programmer",
        tasksNumber: 1,
        isAtWork: true,
        disabled: false,
      },
      {
       id: "id2",
        name: "Jessy",
        prof: "programmer",
        tasksNumber: 6,
        isAtWork: true,
        disabled: false,
      },{
        id: "id3",
        name: "David3",
        prof: "designer",
        tasksNumber: 3,
        isAtWork: true,
        disabled: false,
      },
      {
        id: "id4",
        name: "David4",
        prof: "programmer",
        tasksNumber: 4,
        isAtWork: true,
        disabled: false,
      },{
        id: "id2",
        name: "David2",
        prof: "programmer",
        tasksNumber: 2,
        isAtWork: true,
        disabled: false,
      }]
      
users = allUsers.filter(user => user.prof === 'designer' || ![1, 4].includes(user.tasksNumber)).map(user => { user.disabled = true; return user });


console.log('allUsers = ', allUsers);
```

Comment: Will it set true value only for filtered users who meet the condition requrements?

Comment: yes. It will filter first and set true to the objects which met the condition and filtered from the `filter`

Comment: This mutates the objects in `allUsers` too

Comment: Also in vue js usage is a bit different. I assume it should be like this correct? this,allUsers = this.allUsers.filter(.... Since in the UI I should use allusers instead of other variables

Comment: Also it needs to return the full array of objects and only booleans should be changed for some unmaches inside. Hope it will not create new array only from disabled user objects.

Comment: 1. The above code will change the status of the matched users.
2. It will mutate the original array. So after the change `this.allUsers` will have the changed updated to it.
3. If you are using it in vue, use `this.allUsers`

Comment: I checked your sample it disables all options

Comment: @Dave I have updated my code snippet. you can see the `console.log` showing allUsers with some objects having disabled true.

Comment: it disables options which even not mentioned in filter method

Comment: @Dave because as per the condition, his prof is `designer` and we have user `OR` operator. So it is also disabled

Comment: @StarkButtowski I mean it's disableing other profs e.g. teacher, marketer...

Comment: @Dave I just showed how to achieve the scenario you asked for. For your actual case in your project, either i have to see the actual case or you have to change the filter condition as per your requirement.